# Query perfromance debugging

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

I have recently installed a new module(paypal express) in Oxid 6.0.x backend.
After installation, the backend menu point "orders", in my backend, is timing out. Cause the query needs too long. I am not able to view orders (which is a CMS vendor resource).

I already tried to debug it with our managed hoster support who doubled our ram to increased mysql buffer size as well as php timouts etc. within the php.ini.

After the hoster php.ini change I still see the query with status "Copying to tmp table" even so the hoster has increased the query buffers by more then double

**Question:**
I am really not sure what the problem is. Does someone have an Idea what else I might try?
I cannot imagine that this one small join needs so much buffer space and time to excecute. Especially since the join to payppaypalpluspayment is the same as to oxv_oxpayments_de which is instant and on the same primary key.

This is the query I see running in processlist 
Showing rows 0 - 0 (1 total, Query took 200.9683 seconds.) Has already decreased from about 10 min after the php.ini change

```
select count(*) 
from  `oxorder`
LEFT JOIN `oxv_oxpayments_de` AS `payments` 
    on `payments`.oxid=oxorder.oxpaymenttype
LEFT JOIN `oxv_oxpayments_de` AS pluspayments 
    ON pluspayments.oxid = oxorder.oxpaymenttype
LEFT JOIN payppaypalpluspayment 
    ON payppaypalpluspayment.OXORDERID = oxorder.OXID
LEFT JOIN payppaypalpluspui 
    ON payppaypalpluspui.OXPAYMENTID = payppaypalpluspayment.OXPAYMENTID
where 1  and ( oxorder.oxfolder = 'ORDERFOLDER_NEW' )
```

count(*) Result 150000
The problem may be this join, the others are instant results
rows 0 - 0 (1 total, Query took 153.2391 seconds.)

```
Select count(*) from  `oxorder`
LEFT JOIN payppaypalpluspayment 
    ON payppaypalpluspayment.OXORDERID = oxorder.OXID
```

**EXPLAIN**

```
id select_type  table                   type    possible_keys   key         key_len     ref     rows        Extra   
1   SIMPLE      oxorder                 index       NULL        MAINIDX     10          NULL    146861      Using index
1   SIMPLE      payppaypalpluspayment   index       NULL        OXORDERID   32          NULL    2630        Using where; Using index; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join)
1   SIMPLE      payppaypalpluspui       ALL         NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL    519         Using where
```

This explain changed after adding indexes in

> oxorder.OXPAYMENTTYPE;
>   oxorder.oxfolder;
>   payppaypalpluspui.OXPAYMENTID;
>   payppaypalpluspayment.OXPAYMENTID;

```
id  select_type     table                   type    possible_keys   key         key_len ref                                 rows    Extra   
1   SIMPLE          oxorder                 ref     OXFOLDER        OXFOLDER    98      const                               73450   Using index condition
1   SIMPLE          payppaypalpluspayment   ALL     NULL            NULL        NULL    NULL                                2634    Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join)
1   SIMPLE          payppaypalpluspui       ref     OXPAYMENTID     OXPAYMENTID 34      payppaypalpluspayment.OXPAYMENTID   1       Using where; Using index
```

Which seems more strange even so its a litle faster (still 170s)

After this count selects the backend is doing the same query with select oxorder.* and one column from payppaypalpluspui  (takes about 600 seconds)
The UI has then already timed out. When I delete the last two joins and try it manually on the server the query takes < 1sec

**dbs**

```
CREATE TABLE `payppaypalpluspayment` (
 `OXID` char(32) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Payment oxid id',
 `OXORDERID` char(32) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Order id',
 `OXSALEID` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'PayPal Plus payment sale id',
 `OXPAYMENTID` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'PayPal Plus payment id',
 `OXSTATUS` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'PayPal Plus payment status',
 `OXDATECREATED` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'Payment creation date',
 `OXTOTAL` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Total payment amount',
 `OXCURRENCY` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'Payment currency',
 `OXPAYMENTOBJECT` blob NOT NULL COMMENT 'Serialized payment object',
 PRIMARY KEY (`OXID`),
 UNIQUE KEY `OXORDERID` (`OXORDERID`),
 UNIQUE KEY `OXSALEID` (`OXSALEID`)
 KEY `OXPAYMENTID` (`OXPAYMENTID`)    <<< added this index
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='PayPal Plus payment data model'
```

Rows 3,228  InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     11.4 MiB

```
CREATE TABLE `oxorder` (
 `OXID` char(32) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Order id',
 `OXSHOPID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'Shop id (oxshops)',
 `OXUSERID` char(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'User id (oxuser)',
 `OXORDERDATE` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'Order date',
 `OXORDERNR` varchar(16) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Order number',
 .....
 PRIMARY KEY (`OXID`),
 KEY `MAINIDX` (`OXSHOPID`,`OXSTORNO`,`OXORDERDATE`),
 KEY `OXORDERNR` (`OXORDERNR`)
 KEY `OXPAYMENTTYPE` (`OXPAYMENTTYPE`),  <<<< added this index
 KEY `OXFOLDER` (`OXFOLDER`)             <<<< added this index
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Shop orders information'
```

149,068     InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     258.1 MiB

```
CREATE TABLE `payppaypalpluspui` (
 `OXID` char(32) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Payment oxid id',
 `OXPAYMENTID` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'PayPal Plus payment id',
 `OXREFERENCENUMBER` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'PayPal Plus PuI reference_number',
 `OXBANKNAME` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'PayPal Plus PuI banking instruction bank name',
 `OXACCOUNTHOLDER` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'PayPal Plus PuI banking instruction account holder',
 `OXIBAN` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'PayPal Plus PuI banking instruction IBAN',
 `OXBIC` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'PayPal Plus PuI banking instruction BIC',
 `OXDUEDATE` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'PayPal Plus PuI due date',
 `OXTOTAL` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'PayPal Plus PuI Total invoice amount',
 `OXCURRENCY` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'PayPal Plus PuI invoice currency',
 `OXPUIOBJECT` text NOT NULL COMMENT 'JSON representation of the payment instructions',
 PRIMARY KEY (`OXID`)
 KEY `OXPAYMENTID` (`OXPAYMENTID`)   <<<< added this index
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='PayPal Plus Pay upon Invoice data model'
```

Rows 655    InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     1.5 MiB

innodb buffer pool = 8 GiB 
RAM 10 GiB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly, they were missing some indexes.  Shame on them.

First, is 150K the correct answer?  Keep in mind that all the `JOINs` are done first, thereby exploding the number of rows, *then* the `COUNT` is done.  Also, do you really need `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN`?

What kind of value is in `VARCHAR(32)`?  Some kind of hash?  For large tables, that can make the query I/O-bound.  Please provide the table sizes and the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size` and how much RAM you have.  With those, I can judge whether this is a real problem, or whether the tables are not yet big enough to cause trouble.

If the `VARCHAR(32)` are hex strings, then packing them and putting them into `BINARY(16)` would save a lot of space.

`payppaypalpluspayment` has 3 Unique keys.  That is generally unreasonable.  But I guess you have no control over that?

`DOUBLE` for money?  Ouch.  (This is an oft-discussed topic on this forum.)

Please pass your indexes and my comments on to Oxid.

Plus (very important):  Use the same `CHARACTER SET` and `COLLATION` for any columns that you are `JOINing` on.  (See oysteing's answer in your dup Question.)

Comment: 150k rows, I limited this to 20k by changing oxorder.oxfolder of older orders. The Varchar(32) is an alphanumeric value auto generated by the CMS e.g. "bd8100463bb25d58b67a8259d9b52273"   innodb buffer pool = 8 GiB RAM 10 GiB, I could change the Unique keys, but that would not be update secure

Comment: Scratch one thought -- The data and indexes easily fits in the buffer_pool.  So, after sluggishness on startup, you won't be I/O-bound.  `UNIQUE` and `PRIMARY` keys have the same properties, except that `PRIMARY` is "clustered" with the data.

Comment: This was correct, I changed all columns mentioned in the joins to utf8_general_ci and the excecution time went donw from ~25sec to 0.1208. Thanks